# Changing array inside the main function. Error:assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C and I can't find an answer. How can i change array in main function? Please, help. Thank you. Sorry for my bad English.

```
char name [] = "Maks";
printf ("&s",name);
name = "Alex"; 
printf ("&s",name);
```

So my question is how can i change the value of stray name during program. I want to change the name from Maks to Alex.  Thank you.

Comment: `strcpy(name, "Alex");` ... but **do not** copy more than the array can hold. `strcpy(name, "Paula"); /* error! buffer overflow */`

Comment: Please change `printf ("&s",name);` to `printf ("%s",name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `strcpy()` function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char name[5] = "Mark";
    printf("%s\n", name);
    char get[5] = "Alex";
    strcpy(name, get);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pointer.
Also probably to add **\n** (new line) to **printf** statements.

```c
char *name = "Maks";
printf ("%s\n", name);
name = "Alex";
printf ("%s\n",name);
```

Also please check your formatting, as your piece of code does not read well.

Comment: `char name[1000] = "Maks";` should be enough to use arrays for the next few years :)